# Comparing and discarding two consecutive elements not complying certain condition in a list using Python

Tags: python, arrays, compare, element

So I have this list in Python that I am showing below, and  for the sake of simplicity I'll name it as `p`:

```
 [[11 10]
  [12  9]
  [13  9]
  [13 10]
  [14  8]
  [14 10]
  [15  7]
  [15  9]
  [16  8]
  [17  7]
  [18  2]
  [18  8]
  [19  1]
  [19  7]
  [20  1]
  [20  2]
  [21  2]
  [21  4]
  [22  1]
  [22  3]
  [23  4]
  [24  3]
  [25  4]
  [25  6]
  [26  3]
  [26  5]
  [27  5]
  [27  6]
  [28  8]
  [28 10]
  [29  6]
  [30  5]
  [31  7]
  [31  9]
  [32  1]
  [32  2]
  [33  4]
  [33  6]
  [34  3]
  [34  5]]
```

What I am trying to do is to compare consecutive pairs and then let only the elements with the same `p[0]`. In this sense, one can note that the pairs with `p[0]= 11,12,16,17,23,24,29,30` will not survive and then `p` will become:

```
[[13  9]
 [13 10]
 [14  8]
 [14 10]
 [15  7]
 [15  9]
 [18  2]
 [18  8]
 [19  1]
 [19  7]
 [20  1]
 [20  2]
 [21  2]
 [21  4]
 [22  1]
 [22  3]
 [25  4]
 [25  6]
 [26  3]
 [26  5]
 [27  5]
 [27  6]
 [28  8]
 [28 10]
 [31  7]
 [31  9]
 [32  1]
 [32  2]
 [33  4]
 [33  6]
 [34  3]
 [34  5]]
```

What would be a way of doing this in python? I'd be glad if somebody could give me an idea.

Comment: Do you assume that the list must have been sorted or is this just the example. I gave a simple loop that allows for a non sorted list and a case in which more than two pairs have the match. The restriction on the list characteristics allow more (and simpler) solutions.

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't assume it, but the program I have that created this list will always sort them in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the original question was "compare consecutive pairs and then let only the elements with the same p[0]" which means that one should not sort the original list. If the original list is sorted, then pairs which would otherwise not be "consecutive" will be picked up and kept.  While the sample list was sorted, I will not assume that to be the case so that this will also handle a case such as

```
[[13, 5],
 [13, 2],
 [14, 9],
 [13. 6]]
```

to generate

```
[[13, 5],
 [13, 2]]
```

I will show a simple loop in order to make it easier to understand, but list comprehension can make it shorter. Note that Counter requires python 2.7

```
prev = None
newp = []
length = len(p) - 1
for i in range(length):
  if p[i][0] == p[i+1][0] or p[i][0] == prev:
    newp.append(p[i])
    prev = p[i][0]

if p[length][0] == p[length-1][0]:
  newp.append(p[length])
```

This will create the new list as you want

Comment: Just one note, there is a typo error in the 4th line. It should read p[i+1][0] instead of p[i+1]{0].

Comment: This also works well. And I get exactly the same result that for the answer given by @YS-L. However, if I have understood correctly this code is way more fundamental and then more suitable for diverse cases. So, I will come later to choose the "correct" answer for this. I will test more. Thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input list is named as `lst`, and that you want to kill items with lonely first element *globally*, you can do this:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(zip(*lst)[0])
result = [p for p in lst if cnt[p[0]] > 1]
print result
```

Output:

```
[[13, 9], [13, 10], [14, 8], [14, 10], [15, 7], [15, 9], [18, 2], [18, 8], [19, 1], [19, 7], [20, 1], [20, 2], [21, 2], [21, 4], [22, 1], [22, 3], [25, 4], [25, 6], [26, 3], [26, 5], [27, 5], [27, 6], [28, 8], [28, 10], [31, 7], [31, 9], [32, 1], [32, 2], [33, 4], [33, 6], [34, 3], [34, 5]]
```

---

**But the code above is indeed incorrect** -- I overlooked the question's requirement on *consecutiveness*. For the sake of completeness, let me write the supposedly correct solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
result = []
for _, k in groupby(lst, itemgetter(0)):
    k = list(k)
    if len(k) > 1:
        result.extend(k)
print result
```

They should produce the same result for this specific example though. You should test with a trickier input such as

```
[[11,0],[11,0],[12,0],[13,0],[12,0],[13,0]]
```

and the only the second solution will give the correct answer based on your requirements.

Comment: However the question was to match consecutive pairs only. This would match to any other pair in the list.

Comment: This worked. But I will test what @sabbahillel wrote with the code he's proposed below. Thank you very much all for your answers. I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

writing a generator make it quite readable (you name what you are doing):

```
def find_pairs(items):
    last = (None, None)
    for item in items:
        if item[0] == last[0]:
            yield last
            yield item
        last = item

print [x for x in find_pairs(p)]
```

Comment: This picks up any match in the list not consecutive pair matches

Comment: @sabbahillel could you give me test case where it fails in your opinion? For me it works fine.

Comment: For example consider the case of elements 1, 2, and 3 passing the match. The correct result is to have elements 1, 2, and 3 as the start of the results list. I think that your code would double elemtnt 2 since the first time it element 1 would be last and element 2 would be item. The next time element 3 would be item and element 2 would be last. Thus you would see element 2 twice in your answer list.

Comment: this is matter of how you understand 'returning pairs', if 3 consecutive elements match, they are 2 pairs.

Comment: Yes. every time a question is asked there seems to be an ambiguity that can cause a difference in the answer desired. I suppose that we should ask @muammar what he would want to see if there are three in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions using list comprehension:

1. Idea is to look forward and backward and select if there is a match. To avoid `IndexError` at boundary cases, using `i > 0` and `i < len(A)-1`

   ```
   >>> ans = [el for i, el in enumerate(A) if (i > 0 and A[i-1][0] == el[0]) or \
   (i < len(A)-1 and A[i+1][0] == el[0])]
   ```
2. Prepend and append dummy values to avoid handling of IndexError

   ```
   >>> A = [[None, None]] + A + [[None, None]]
   >>> ans = [el for i, el in enumerate(A) if A[i-1][0] == el[0] or \
   A[i+1][0] == el[0]]
   ```
3. Use zip to get next and previous element

   ```
   >>> A = [[None, None]] + A + [[None, None]]
   >>> ans = [e2 for e1, e2, e3 in zip(A, A[1:], A[2:]) if e2[0] == e1[0] or \
   e2[0] == e3[0]]
   ```